# Poi jars exists but getting this compile time error - XWPFRun.addPicture(FileInputStream, int, String, int, int) is undefined

Tags: java, eclipse, apache-poi, undefined, xwpf

I am trying to generate a word document using an existing template. I just replaced my existing jars of version 3.8 with 3.11 version of jars because the addPciture() function was not available in 3.8 version. But the error didn't go off. When I checked the existence of the function it was there in XWPFRun class. Please check the image below

[image]

These are the jars I have in my classpath of the project:

[image]

I imported the relevant XWPF classes as shown below:

[image]

But still, I am getting this error:

[image]

Intellisense is also not able to find the function:

[image]

Somehow it is still showing the functions from previous POI version I think. These are the steps I tried so far to resolve this particular issue:

1. Clean Build.
2. Cleared eclipse workspace.
3. Tried some other versions such as 3.13 (same issue)
4. Created another project with the same jars of version 3.11. (Working and giving expected result). Eclipse is able to identify the same function in some different project. Below is the image of that different project.

[image]

Need help to resolve this issue.

Thanks

Comment: Why use such an old version?

Comment: Same problem with newer versions as well. By the way, this application was built in 2014. So, If I change to latest version it will create so many problems and I may have to make lots of changes that I really don't need now.

Comment: Are you using maven?

Comment: Yes, I am trying this approach right now. I have converted my project into the maven project. Hopefully, it will resolve any conflict issue.

Comment: If you have your pom set up properly, run `mvn eclipse:clean eclipse:eclipse -U` to clean and rebuild the project as well as updating all dependencies. You can also exclude specific transient dependencies using `dependencyManagement`

Comment: I think some other jar may have the same package. I will let you know if I find the culprit.

Comment: Issue resolved! I found the jar which has the same package:  org.eclipse.birt.runtime_4.2.2.v20130216-1152.jar. Thank you XtremeBaumer